# onPress form submission and value handling

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-form, native-base

I'm trying to submit a form and call a reducer with the form values, however I cannot manage to get the values.

Here's what my form looks like:

```
<Field
  name="email"
  component={this.renderInput}
  type="email"
  validate={[email, required]}
/>
<Field
  name="password"
  component={this.renderInput}
  type="password"
  validate={[alphaNumeric, minLength8, maxLength15, required]}
/>

<Button
  rounded
  primary
  block
  large
  style={styles.loginBtn}
  onPress={() => this.login()}
>
```

and here is what the login function looks like:

```
login() {
  if (this.props.valid) {
    //do something here, but how to get the data?
  } else {
    Toast.show({
      text: "Enter Valid Username & password!",
      duration: 2500,
      position: "top",
      textStyle: { textAlign: "center" }
    });
  }
}
```

I can click the button and get to the `login()` function, and even pass the if (`this.props.valid`) check, but I cannot figure out how to get the values for email and password in the login function.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store the inputs of your  in memory in order to access. While  isn't a native component, this is how I would set/get this value using :

NOTE: You may want to search your package's documentation for an onChangeText() callback.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class SO_LoginExample extends Component<{}> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: undefined,
            password: undefined, 
        }
    }

    login() {
        console.log(this.state.email, this.state.password);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
                    onChangeText={(inputVal) => this.setState({email: inputVal})}
                value={this.state.email}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    onChangeText={(inputVal) => this.setState({password: inputVal})}
                value={this.state.password}
                />
                <Button
                    title="Login"
                    onPress={() => this.login()}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }

}
```